# CryptographicEngine Decrypt throw Value does not fall within the expected range exception in Decrypt mathod

Tags: c#, encryption, windows-runtime, cryptography, windows-phone-8.1

i try to use that code but i get Value does not fall within the expected range exception in Decrypt mathod when the Decrypt line happen

this is singleton class so he create the key once

```
{
    public class CryptographyProvider
    {
        private CryptographicKey key;
        public CryptographyProvider()
        {
            String AsymmetricAlgName = Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core.AsymmetricAlgorithmNames.RsaPkcs1;
            AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider asym = AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(AsymmetricAlgName);
             key = asym.CreateKeyPair(512);

        }
        public string Encrypt(string source)
        {
            IBuffer buf = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(source, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf16BE);
            IBuffer enc = CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(key, buf, null);
            byte[] encryptedbyteArr;
            CryptographicBuffer.CopyToByteArray(enc, out encryptedbyteArr);
            var ret =  Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedbyteArr);

            return ret;
        }

        public string Decrypt(string source)
        {
            IBuffer buf = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(source, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf16BE);
            IBuffer enc = CryptographicEngine.Decrypt(key, buf, null);
            byte[] encryptedbyteArr;
            CryptographicBuffer.CopyToByteArray(enc, out encryptedbyteArr);
            var ret = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedbyteArr);
            return ret;
        }
    }
}
```

what wrong in my code?

Comment: Copy, don't summarize, the error message and any stack trace you receive.

Comment: error message: Value does not fall within the expected range.
stackTrace:    at Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core.CryptographicEngine.Decrypt(CryptographicKey key, IBuffer data, IBuffer iv)
   at Poc.WindowsPhone.Providers.CryptographyProvider.Decrypt(String source)

Comment: @AviGe: Did you find solution i am facing the same issue